# grails mybatis-plugin validation location

Tags: grails, grails-orm, mybatis

I cite from mybatis plugin documentation:

> "When working with MyBatis plugin your "Domain" classes should be
>   located in src/groovy and not in grails-app/domain. This is necessary
>   to avoid conflict with GROM since MyBatis plugin can coexist with
>   existing GORM Domain classes."

So where should the validation and constraints be located, when I want to use grails with MyBatis plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a @Validateable annotation to any Groovy class in Grails, and you will be able to validate it... The Plugin currently doesn't check for any validation errors so you will have to implement that code yourself.

From official Grails documentation:

> Classes which define the static constraints property and are annotated
>   with @Validateable can be made validateable by the framework

http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/validation.html#validationNonDomainAndCommandObjectClasses

You could even write a custom MyBatis Interceptor (see https://github.com/fzilic/Grails-MyBatis/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/mybatis/locking/OptimisticLockingInterceptor.groovy) and register it after the SqlSession is created...

Currently the MyBatis plugin doesn't support registering custom Interceptors in it's configuration, but they could be added to the interceptor chain

```groovy
def factory = GrailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("sqlSessionFactoryBean_dataSource") 

factory.configuration.interceptorChain.addInterceptor(Interceptor)
```

Support for this might be added in future versions.